Avoiding upstream resonances with harmonic filters
I've got quite a few issues with harmonic currents on a VFD so I designed a (fat) harmonic filter. It's single phase so it's designed to block the third and the fifth harmonic (150Hz and 250Hz, here).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The left side models the mains supply, the load is here represented by a 15 ohm resistor. For a transient analysis it needs to be replaced with something more realistic (like a diode bridge and a capacitor) but for AC this is OK.
Usually these filters are done in a shunt topology with a blocking reactor but I opted for a series filter because I can't put a disconnect contactor on the shunt branches (otherwise they'll suck current even when it's not needed).
Now, it works, both on SPICE and in the lab (it's big and heavy as it should be) with a resistive load of 15-30 Ohm (which is the design value) but there's a thing worrying me. The seventh and ninth are under control, until I rise the source impedance.


It's a known fact that these filters can interact with the upstream distribution system since the inductive component of the distribution can be significant. With a nominal LISN-like 250µH the result is good (that would be a 0.4+j0.08 source impedance); given that the supply for harmonic testing has a really low impedence I should pass compliance with this. However real world supplies have really worse inductive component. I found in a paper (Evaluation of Fault Levels and Power Supply Network Impedances in 230/400 V 50 Hz Generic Distribution Systems, DOI 10.1109/TPWRD.2016.2609643) a worst residential case of 0.46+j0.45 which is about 1.5mH. With such a source, the series filters seems to resonate on the higher harmonics

Every paper I read warns of this issue but nobody gives useful indication ("just be careful"); I could lower the quality factor but the loss on the filter would be even more substantial (we already are at 25W, excluding the parasitics). A commercial shunt 16A single phase filter dissipates about 150W so maybe that's actually the right solution...
It seems that the issue is the second 'hill' in the AC response but that moves with the input impedance. Any suggestion on how to stabilise this thing?

Do put in your    single phase bridge  and filter cap ,Then look at your current wave in the time domain,

How can you get the 2nd waveform with the test circuit you have shown? What does the AC response look like when the source impedance is low and, where did you put the generator to produce that AC response?

The transient analysis simply has a diode bridge on the right side; the current in the time domain is the one shown


Usually these filters are done in a shunt topology with a blocking reactor but I opted for a series filter because I can't put a disconnect contactor on the shunt branches (otherwise they'll suck current even when it's not needed).< What do you mean with this?


@Antonio51 shunt harmonic filters are only put online when the load is active otherwise they use a considerable amount of power for nothing. Series filter do not have this issue but the behaviour is different

Usually a switching frequency of VFD is important when designing a filter. We do tend to  filter out that frequency in order to prevent high capacitive currents and minimize HF leak currents. Now why are you so interested to suppress 3rd, 5th,..base harmonics? Seems pretty useless to me. You do also have to calculate the voltage drop, to see if enough power will come out of this setup.

actually they come not from the switching process but from the rectifier pack at the input. It's not useless because we have the EN 61000 (EMC) series that forces us to limit them for compliance. So it's huge passive filter time or horribly expensive active filter (VAr generators) time

The figures show I(R1), but this is one of the loss resistors?  How is the harmonic source or load modeled anyway, clearly the schematic does not show such?  In any case, the schematic shown does not seem consistent with the waveforms given.


With such a source [i.e. one with 1.5 mH inductance], the series filters seems to resonate on the higher harmonics

Not quite.
Here is your circuit with some slight changes. I have changed the value of L3 to 1.5 mH, to correspond with the "worst case" source impedance, and I have changed L1 and L2 to 11 mH and 4 mH, respectively, to give resonant frequencies that more closely match 150 Hz and 250 Hz. I have also omitted the load, so that we can see the admittance (the inverse of the impedance) of the notch filters together with the source admittance. This will allow us to observe a resonant peak at which the circuit may ring that is otherwise obscured.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here is the magnitude of the admittance:

From this plot, one can easily see a peak in the magnitude of the admittance at around 617 Hz. The filter network together with the input inductance is likely to ring at this frequency if the circuit receives an appropriate stimulus and the load has a sufficiently low impedance at that frequency. Note the difference between this plot and the plot shown in the original question (which includes a load resistance), where the 617 Hz peak is not noticeable. Note also, that peak frequency is determined by the filter network, together with the source impedance, and is completely unrelated to harmonics of the input frequency.
From the comments:

The transient analysis simply has a diode bridge on the right side; the current in the time domain is the one shown

Actually, I believe the your simulation was performed with both a diode bridge and a smoothing capacitor, plus a load.
The full wave rectifier plus the smoothing capacitor, provide the stimulus, and the necessary low impedance of the load at that frequency.
Here is a circuit with the 1.5 mH source inductance, bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor.

simulate this circuit
Here is a time domain simulation of the input current, the current through the smoothing capacitor, and the current through the load resistor.

Now, here is your circuit without the smoothing capacitor

simulate this circuit
The absence of ringing when the smoothing capacitor is omitted, is due to the low admittance of the load at the ringing frequency. If the smoothing capacitor is present, but is of a smallish value, it will tend combine with the net capacitative reactance of the filter network at higher frequencies, and raise the ringing frequency.


Any suggestion on how to stabilise this thing?

The use of passive filters (rather than active/switching) results in high values for inductances and capacitances at low (i.e. mains) frequencies. However, if passive filters are what you want, and you can live with the high values, a solution may be to add a band-pass and/or low-pass filter to the filter cascade. Because the natural frequency of the ringing will vary with the input line impedance, a notch filter would be problematic.
Here is a potential solution.

simulate this circuit

The 100 uF and 100 mH values for the 50 Hz band-pass filter can be changed, as long as the product of the two values remains relatively constant. You should have
$$LC \approx \frac{1}{4\pi^2 50^2} \approx 10.13 x 10^{-6} HF$$

Series filter will cause a voltage drop that probably will cause another problems to the drive. Most of VDF have some user free outputs, so you can adjust one of them to be active when the drive is running, and close a line contactor for the filters.
To lower losses, see C-type filter, tuned at 3rd harmonic and check for 5th and higher. The advantage is that L and C are parallel with the damping resistor, reducing the current through R. Also you save some elements. See drawings and plot, it is an example, not calculated components.
You can take a look at this web: https://www.pscad.com/webhelp/Master_Library_Models/Passive/Filters/Passive_Filter_Design.htm

